# Doctrine query builder and manytomany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a simple problem.

I have some users. I have some contacts. Single `User` can have some Contacts. One `Contact` may be owned by many `Users`, a simple `ManyToMany` relation:

```
User <-> user_contact <-> Contact
```

How can I build a query that will return something like all `Contact`s not owned by a `User`. Those contacts may be owned by another `User` or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `MEMBER OF` option will do the magic.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$em->createQuery("select c from Contract c where :userId NOT MEMBER OF c.Users")
   ->setParameter("groupId", <<YOUR_USER_ENTITY_OR_USER_ID>>)
   ->getResult();
```

Ofcourse I don't know your entities, but I think this will give you some idea.

Comment: Really nice, It does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!